# Extruded spline (THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject) not responding to Three.Ray

Tags: three.js

I have a page using elements from the [extruded spline example](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_geometry_extrude_splines.html) and the [mouse tooltip example](http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Mouse-Tooltip.html). Trying to debug the starting elements of this projects before moving on. The mouse tooltip is working on a variety of objects except for the extruded spline.

Using webGL renderer, if that matters.

Code for spline creation (not including Vector3 lines or circular extrude):

```
function addGeometry( geometry, color, x, y, z, rx, ry, rz, s, name ) {
    var mesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( geometry, [
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: color } )
    ] );
    mesh.position.set( x, y, z );
    mesh.scale.set( s, s, s );
    mesh.name = name;
    scene.add( mesh );
}
```

The intersect/Three.Ray code in update() is the same as the example linked above. I also tried adding the spline to a parent but still no changes onMouseOver. Later this week I might transition over to ThreeX DOM events and Tween :D

Mini issue which could be separate questions:

- Witnessing some inaccuracy in Ray-linked OnMouseOver events on planes. It could also be the fact I'm using large distances? Planes are 1000x1000 and camera is 2000px away. I know that's ridiculous and I'm in the process of fixing that as well.

Thanks for listening!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only provided code snippets, here is a guess: Because a Multi-material object is hierarchical, you need to set the recursive flag in `ray.intersectObjects()` to true like so:

```
var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( scene.children, true );
```

Comment: No change in result after that. I might have tried it a couple days ago and not mentioned in my synopsis of the program. I'll keep keep messing with it. Thanks though!

Comment: Can you provide a live example?

Comment: Right now I'm just running local with port forwarding. I've seen a couple sites for live script sharing. Any preferences?

Comment: jsfiddle.net works great. It's easy for others to edit. If you have textures, you can place all your files in a public dropbox folder and provide a link.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I put this problem aside to push forward in other areas. Here is a link to my current draft: http://talbot.frisbeebiotech.com/ I'm using a different hover method but it still doesn't work on extruded splines.

Comment: Sorry, this is too much for me to debug for you. If you have a problem, and can crate a small jsfiddle to show an isolated example, I can help you. My guess is that it has nothing to do with extruded splines, but instead with the coordinates of the vector you are un-projecting. Look at the three.js examples to see how they do picking.